# sql how to sum count value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which shows a employees id, name date ,time and count the repeat employee number. Below is my sql code. Now i want to get the sum of  count value, but it seems i can't use like sum(count(*)) value, i know i should use sub query, but still don't get it how to make it work. Any one have idea how to solve this ?

```
select distinct a.employee_id,b.name,a.type,a.date,a.time,count(*)
from deal_records a, staff_table b
where a.employee_id = b.employee_id && a.date='2016-12-23' && b.name like "L%" 
group by a.employee_id   ;
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You are using a join syntax that was made redundant even before the first MySQL version was ever launched. Use explicit ANSI joins instead. As to your query: it looks wrong. What are `type` and `time` supposed to contain? There is probably more than one `deal_record` per `employee_id` and `date` (otherwise you wouldn't have to count), so which record is the DBMS to get the values from? It will pick the values arbitrarily. Addditionally the `DISTINCT` is superfluous, because all grouped by columns (only `employee_id` in your case) are in the select clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered removing the `group by`?

```
select count(*)
from deal_records d join
     staff_table s
     on d.employee_id = s.employee_id 
where d.date = '2016-12-23' and
      s.name like 'L%';
```

Comment: The conditions on single tables should be in the `WHERE` clause; `ON` should just be for joining conditions relating the tables. Although MySQL allows both forms.

Comment: @Barmar . . . I'm pretty sure you wouldn't downvote me for that.  I don't disagree aesthetically, but for an `inner join`, the `on` and `where` are equivalent.

Comment: thx for reply , i have tried it's working. but i want the result should also shows time , name , date these information.and now i have new question, i want to show in the one month, for each day, there should be a result show sum for count